# How to know the field name in Generator class when using @GeneratorType in JPA/Hibernates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

As part of sequence generation for non-primary key, I am using `@GeneratorType` on entity field. In generator class I require to know a field on that it has been called. Help is appreciated.

```java
@Entity(name = "student")
public class Student {

   @GeneratorType(type = IdGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
   private Integer secId;
}
    
public class IdGenerator implements ValueGenerator<Integer>{

   @Override
   public Integer generateValue(Session session, Object owner) {
      // I want secId here
   }
}
```

Comment: Try this: `((Student) owner).secId`

Comment: It should be dynamic in nature. I will be having many fields with same @GeneratorType.

Comment: So, you can define common interface and then cast `Object owner` to this interface.

Comment: Any sample code pls?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like this:

```java
public interface EntityId {
   Integer getId();
}

@Entity(name = "student")
public class Student implements EntityId {
   @GeneratorType(type = IdGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
   private Integer secId;

   @Override
   public Integer getId() {
      return secId;
   }

   // ...
}

@Entity
public class OtherEntity implements EntityId {

   // ...
}


public class IdGenerator implements ValueGenerator<Integer> {
   @Override
   public Integer generateValue(Session session, Object owner) {
      if (!(owner instanceof EntityId)) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("IdGenerator can be used only with entities that implement EntityId interface");
      }
      
      // I want secId here
      Integer id = ((EntityId) owner).getId();
   }
}
```

If you use Java 14 or higher you can use [pattern matching for instanceof](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305) as more elegant construction.

```java
public class IdGenerator implements ValueGenerator<Integer> {
   @Override
   public Integer generateValue(Session session, Object owner) {
      if (owner instanceof EntityId entityId) {
         // I want secId here
         Integer id = entityId.getId();

         // ...
      } else {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("IdGenerator can be used only with entities that implement EntityId interface");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. Even we implement an interface here, if we have more than one @GeneratorType in the same entity, we cannot pass it dynamically right.  

Ex: I have below two entries in same Student entity:
@GeneratorType(type = IdGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
   private Integer deptId;
@GeneratorType(type = IdGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
   private Integer secId;

Then I cannot increase the override methods in interface, which I cannot typecast dynamically in Generator class.

Comment: Yes, this approach will not work for more than one @GeneratorType in the same entity.

Comment: But it looks like this is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).